# Flutter convert ByteData to File

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I'm using this template/package to draw in Flutter https://pub.dev/packages/scribble/example.
Now I want to convert the drawn image to a `File`. So that I can use it in my `tflite` model. To predict the image the `runModelOnImage` (`tflite` package) function requires a path to the image.
The used `scribble` package, provides the `saveImage` function to return the drawn image as `byteData`:

```
// saveImage
    Future<void> _saveImage(BuildContext context) async {
        final image = await notifier.renderImage();
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("Your Image"),
            content: Image.memory(image.buffer.asUint8List()),
          ),
        );
      }
```

How can I transform the byteData image to a File so I can use it in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByteData is an abstraction for:

A fixed-length, random-access sequence of bytes that also provides random and unaligned access to the fixed-width integers and floating point numbers represented by those bytes.
As Gunter mentioned in the comments, you can use File.writeAsBytes. It does require a bit of API work to get from ByteData to a List, however.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

Future<void> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
  final buffer = data.buffer;
  return new File(path).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}
```

You can read more about this on [here](https://newbedev.com/how-to-write-a-bytedata-instance-to-a-file-in-dart)